# ExtJs - Render object 'layout form' dynamically in DOM

Tags: dom, extjs

I have a function :

```
var my_form = function() {
    return {
        layout:'form',
        items: [
            {
                xtype:'textfield',
                fieldLabel: "Name",
                maxLength: 255
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

I want to render it dynamically. This doesn't work :

```
var t = Ext.DomHelper.createTemplate(my_form()).compile();
Ext.DomHelper.insertBefore('my_div', t);
```

How to do this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using createTemplate() for a specific reason? If not, you could change your first line to var t = new Ext.Form(my_form());

Comment: @Paolo, I think you should put it as answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 1):

I found out it can work this way: first create a div via DomHelper, then create the FormPanel using the "renderTo" config option.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var formdiv = Ext.DomHelper.insertBefore('my_div', {tag: 'div', id: 'form_div' } );

    var my_form = function() {
        return {
            layout:'form',
            renderTo:'form_div',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: "Name",
                    maxLength: 255
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    var t = new Ext.FormPanel(my_form());

});
```

Comment: No, no specific reason. I'm tested with `new Ext.Panel()` (new Ext.Form doesn't work). But insertBefore display `'+this.header.dom.innerHTML+''; if(this.iconCls){ this.setIconClass(this.iconCls); } } } if(this.floating){ this.makeFloating(this.floating); } if(this.collapsible && this.titleCollapse && this.header){ this.mon(this.header, 'click', this.toggleCollapse, this); this.header.setStyle('cursor', 'pointer'); } if(ts){ this.addTool.apply(this, t......`, and no it's content ...

Comment: @Paolo @barbacan It should be Ext.FormPanel(my_form) and not Ext.Form(my_form)

Comment: it's the same problem : the method insertBefore doesn't display content of my_form. Create FormPanel is good idea, but now, how to display this FormPanel ?

Comment: use the show() .. you need to refer to the API documentation! http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/

Comment: thanks Paolo. show() show my form, but it's attached on tag body, not on "my_div" ... I'm lost in the dense API documentation!

Comment: @barbacan maybe my new answer will do

Comment: almost! I'm rendering form in a window (not a div off DOM). if I add a div dynamically, and I set renderTo (`var form = my_form(); form.renderTo='id_div_dynamic'; var t = new Ext.FormPanel(form);`), this changes nothing.